# How to fix header in bfSize field

Tags: c, image-resizing, cs50, bmp

I am in week 4 of Harvard's CS50. I am currently working on Resize - so enlarging an existing BMP by a particular factor (between 1 and 100).

My code compiles and resizes the image accurately, however when running CS50's Check50 it indicates unexpected errors in the bfSize field, e.g. expected 0xae, not 0x5a in header field bfSize.

I am completely new to programming so forgive me for any stupid questions.

This is a link to my code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me50/NinaIMW/cs50/problems/2019/x/resize/less/resize.c?token=ALYWHW7TNZRPFYTB73JSUCK5LBMXC

This is what Check50 returns when I test my code:

````
:) resize.c and bmp.h exist.
:) resize.c compiles.
:) doesn't resize small.bmp when n is 1
:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 2
    expected 0xae, not 0x5a in header field bfSize
:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 3
    expected 0x132, not 0x5a in header field bfSize
:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 4
    expected 0x1e6, not 0x5a in header field bfSize
:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 5
    expected 0x306, not 0x5a in header field bfSize
:( resizes large.bmp correctly when n is 2
    expected 0x6f6, not 0x1e6 in header field bfSize
:( resizes smiley.bmp correctly when n is 2
    expected 0x336, not 0xf6 in header field bfSize
:( resizes smiley.bmp correctly when n is 3
    expected 0x6f6, not 0xf6 in header field bfSize```
````

Comment: [Your link](https://github.com/me50/NinaIMW/blob/cs50/problems/2019/x/resize/less/resize.c) is not working...

Comment: Apologies. Didn't realize you had to share the raw, it should work now. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me50/NinaIMW/cs50/problems/2019/x/resize/less/resize.c?token=ALYWHW7TNZRPFYTB73JSUCK5LBMXC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have small.bmp (so I can't try) but I would suggest to change :

```
newBf.bfSize = bi.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
```

to

```
newBf.bfSize = newBi.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
```

You were still using the old `bi` instead of `newBi` to calculate the `newBf.bfSize`.

Comment: Oh dear, yes! Thanks so much for spotting that. That now works a lot better. It is still erroring when n is 2,3 or 4 for small. `:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 2
    expected 0xae, not 0xb4 in header field bfSize
:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 3
    expected 0x132, not 0x144 in header field bfSize
:( resizes small.bmp correctly when n is 4
    expected 0x1e6, not 0x20a in header field bfSize` Do you think that might be a padding issue? Small is 3 by 3 so 9 bytes per scanline so not a multiple of 4, while smiley is 8 by 8 so 24 per scanline.

Comment: This line is used before calculating the correct `newBI.biWidth`, that looks wrong : `int newPadding = (4 - (newBi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;` You should put this line after calculating `newBI.biWidth` (but before using `newPadding`).

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working perfectly now! Thanks so much!

Comment: @NinaIMW If you are happy with my answer, could you upvote and accept it ? Thank you

Comment: Hey, I don’t have enough reputation points yet as I’m quite new to stack overflow. I have hit the upvote arrow quite a few times though. And stack overflow say they take these into account.  :)

Comment: @NinaIMW What about [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ? ;-)